# Python: How to extend the content of a list store in a dict?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am facing a really simple and strange problem with Python.

I have a dict with several keys, that contain empty lists.
I want to append/extend the content of lists of specific keys.
The code I therefore think of looks like this

```
d = dict.fromkeys(['A','B','C'],[])
d['A'].append('Hello')
```

However, the result is not what I expect. 
The value of each key is a list containing one element: 'Hello'

```
>>> d
{'A': ['Hello'], 'C': ['Hello'], 'B': ['Hello']}
```

If I try what follows, it results in the same thing

```
d.get('A').append('Bye')
```

What operations I have to do obtain this?

```
>>> d
{'A': ['Hello'], 'C': [], 'B': []}
```

Can someone explains what goes wrong with my syntax?

Answer (score 5):

Your *syntax* is fine, but you're using the *same* list over and over again. Since lists are mutable, when you `append`, you're adding 'Hello' to the same list, which happens to be referenced in three places. What you probably want to do instead is create the dict a little more manually:

```
d = {k:[] for k in ['A', 'B', 'C']}
```

(The above is Python 2.7 or later. For older Python you can use: `dict((k,[]) for k in ['A', 'B', 'C'])`)

Comment: I feel [this small tutorial](http://henry.precheur.org/python/copy_list) helped me understand this python concept the best, since it's slightly different and counter intuitive coming for C/++

Answer (score 4):

You're creating a dictionary with all its values refer to the same instance `[]` as @Aशwini चhaudhary mentioned. 
You may want to use `defaultdict`:

```
In [150]: from collections import defaultdict

In [151]: d = defaultdict(list)

In [152]: d['A'].append('Hello')

In [153]: d
Out[153]: defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'A': ['Hello']})

In [154]: print d['B']
[]
```